# Is there a way to deploy ARM template on every new subscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to run deploy an ARM template on every subscription and on future new subscriptions.
In AWS there's stackset for the organization level and it's working.
How can I achieve the same result in Azure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure **[Blueprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/overview)**:

> Blueprints are a declarative way to orchestrate the deployment of various resource templates and other artifacts such as:
>
> - Role Assignments
> - Policy Assignments  Azure
> - Resource  Manager templates (ARM templates)
> - Resource Groups